# SQL making the decimal to one places

Tags: sql

With this code I keep on getting 3.500000. How do I make it 3.5 with one decimal point? I can get it higher but not lower.

```
(Select AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),Cats)) from @Catsnumber)
```

Comment: Tag dbms product used. (That doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you need it in a calculation, just use `round`. If you need it for presentation, handle it on the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
 Select CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),AVG(Cats))from @Catsnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `ROUND` or `CAST` to a precise numeric data type with the precision you want